# How can I serialize cv::Mat objects using protobuf?

Tags: opencv, protocol-buffers

Is there a gentle solution? (Such as an existing Mat.proto file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a tricky one. The question is do you need all the data and properties from cv::Mat? If yes my condolences, because you would need to map everything to the new protobuf structure.

if you want to have something like this:

```
// make a 7x7 complex matrix filled with 1+3j.
Mat M(7,7,CV_32FC2,Scalar(1,3));
```

The you need something like:

```
message Mat {
  required uint32 xSize = 1; //7
  required uint32 ySize = 2; //7
  required string encoding = 3; //CV_32FC2

  message Scalar { // this is optional
    required uint32 x = 1; 
    required uint32 y = 2; 
    required uint32 z = 3;
  }

  repeated Scalar matrix = 4; // 49 elements
  //note here that the Scalar is a 4-element vector derived from Vec
  //and the matrix should consist of scalars 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will customize my own Mat message.

Answer (score 9):

To serialize an OpenCV matrix using Google Protocol Buffers, inspiration can be taken from the XML/YAML/JSON serialization available in OpenCV by using the FileStorage class. All the information needed is the numbers of rows, the number of columns, the type of elements, the element size and the matrix's raw data.

Here is the .proto definition:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package opencv;

message OcvMat {
    int32 rows = 1;
    int32 cols = 2;
    int32 elt_type = 3;
    int32 elt_size = 4;
    bytes mat_data = 5;
}
```

Here is the serialization code in C++, assuming that we want to save the matrix in a file which will only contain this data:

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::ones(480, 640, CV_8UC3);

//open a file in output, overwrite and binary mode
fstream output("path/to/file.extention", ios::out | ios::trunc | ios::binary);

//create an instance of the class generated by the compilation of the .proto file
opencv::OcvMat serializableMat;

//set the trivial fields
serializableMat.set_rows(m.rows);
serializableMat.set_cols(m.cols);
serializableMat.set_elt_type(m.type());
serializableMat.set_elt_size((int)m.elemSize());

//set the matrix's raw data
size_t dataSize = m.rows * m.cols * m.elemSize();
serializableMat.set_mat_data(m.data, dataSize);

//write to file
if(!serializableMat.SerializeToOstream(&output))
{
    cerr << "error" << endl;
}

output.close();
```

Here is the deserialization code in C++:

```
//open the file where the data was written in input and binary mode
fstream input("path/to/file.extension", ios::in | ios::binary);

//create an instance of the class generated automatically by the compilation of the .proto file
opencv::OcvMat serializableMat;

//create an empty OpenCV matrix
cv::Mat m;

//read the data from the input file into the OcvMat object
if(serializableMat.ParseFromIstream(&input))
{
    //allocate the matrix
    m.create(serializableMat.rows(),
    serializableMat.cols(),
    serializableMat.elt_type());

    //set the matrix's data
    size_t dataSize = serializableMat.rows() *  serializableMat.cols() * serializableMat.elt_size();

    std::copy(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(
            const_cast<char *>(serializableMat.mat_data().data())),
        reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(
            const_cast<char *>(serializableMat.mat_data().data()) + dataSize),
        m.data);
}
else
{
    cerr << "error" << endl;
}

input.close();
```

It is then possible to serialize OpenCV matrices as attributes of more complex serialized objects. The only difference for serialization is that one has to set the data to a pointer to an OcvMat object that is accessed using

```
 myComplexObject.mutable_field_name()
```

, where "filed_name" is the name given to the field of type OcvMat. For deserialization, it will be exactly the same. The OcvMat object contained in the deserialized complex object is accessed by calling

```
myComplexObject.field_name().
```

Comment: How come you don't account for how many channels the matrix has? I have the size calculation as (cols * rows * channels * elementSize). Shoud I ignore the channels?

Comment: @Stewart : this is already covered by the matrix's type and element size. The m.elemSize() method returns the size of an element for all channels, see here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#aba7a5ef00b22b70668fba575005dfe55

This info alone is sufficient to store the matrix's raw data and unpack it with the correct stride information. Again, as explained in my post, I took inspiration from the way matrices are serialized to text files in the existing OpenCV FileStorage class.

Comment: Hi @PierreWargnier thanks for your answer. But after I use cv::dnn::blobFromImage my Mat's rows and cols all change to -1, then I got wrong dataSize.